# how can i remove a wireless driver?

Tags: drivers, uninstall

i want to remove this 2 drivers :

```
PHY     Interface           Driver                 Chipset

phy0      wlan0mon      mac80211_hwsim   Software simulator of 802.11 radio(s) for mac80211

phy1      wlan1         mac80211_hwsim   Software simulator of 802.11 radio(s) for mac80211
```

Comment: Usually, `sudo rmmod mac80211_hwsim` is the way.

Answer (score 2):

Technicaly you can't.

`sudo rmmod mac80211_hwsim` will remove module for this session, but in order to prevent it from autoloading at next start
You may try to backlist it in this way:

```
echo mac80211_hwsim | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

Then reboot.